# how to translate jquery to normal java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

excuse me, can somebody help me translate this code to normal JS(if it is possible)??

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav-accordion').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: true,
        disableLink: true,
        speed: 'slow',
        showCount: false,
        autoExpand: true,
//        cookie: 'dcjq-accordion-1',
        classExpand: 'dcjq-current-parent'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to translate all the code inside the `dcAccordion` plugin to native JavaScript. Not an easy tasks. For the `$(function () {})`, you can do the following:

```
window.ondomready = function () {

};
```

And the ondomready concept is too huge, for a trailer, please look at this answer: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the).

In a nutshell, it says:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
window.addEventListener('load', fn, false );
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", fn);
window.attachEvent("onload", fn);
```